# How do I run an npm library in rust?

Tags: javascript, npm, rust, v8

I want to run this npm library [fabric.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric) server side but I'm thinking of writing my backend in rust, is there a way to use `v8` or something like that so that I can use that library and all it's functionality inside rust?

What I want is that user to be able to save the canvas template which I would do so by using `.toJSON()` and saving it in the database. Then users would be able to call my api and get their canvas as images of multiple size and formats, what I'm gonna do is run `fabric.js` server side (which uses `node-canvas` for a canvas implementation in node) and create dynamic images and serve it to the user.

I could write my backend in JavaScript which would make my life much easier but I was thinking if there's a way to achieve this?

Comment: You want to use a HTML Canvas library...server side...in Rust? That...doesn't really make much sense without some more detail. I'm not saying it *can't* be done, but there's almost certainly an easier/better way...can you drop some more info about what you're trying to achieve with Fabric?

Comment: Added more info above on what i'm trying to do.

Comment: You could do most of your server in Rust and then use a Node server solely for this image generation function.

Comment: yeah, but i don't want to spin up another server just for image generation. i'm thinking of going for either rust or node backend

Comment: SInce the JSON format is determined by Fabric, you'd have to either a) spin up a node.js server to handle just the image generation or b) reverse-engineer the JSON format, convert it, and use image manipulation facilities in Rust.

Comment: Not that I would really recommend it, but you could use something like [deno_core](https://github.com/denoland/deno_core) or even [v8](https://docs.rs/v8) to run JS from Rust

Comment: @xqcccccccccc why do you think that running both Rust and Node server is not a good idea? It doesn't require additional physical/virtual machine.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo it would require separate environments no?

suppose i deploy it to cloud run where i have to build a docker image. You're saying i can have both node and rust installed in that docker image and call javascript functions for image manipulation using node from rust using maybe shell commands? and run my server usually with rust?

Comment: @xqcccccccccc yes, you can install multiple programs in the same docker container, then call one from the other (`spawn` a new nodejs process for each request, pass values via file system, args, and/or `stdin`/`stdout`). You could also run both nodejs and rust in parallel (e.g. using a shell script that starts them) and communicate between them using pipes, rpc, sockets, http, whatever). You can also run two separate containers if you prefer.